# Why is my login_required redirect not working?

Tags: django

I seem to be doing everything correctly, yet I am still receiving a 404 when I try to login into a page that is login_required only rather than being redirected to the login page.

**Settings.py/Login_url**

```
LOGIN_URL = '/dating_app/login/'
```

**dating_app/urls/login**

```
path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'dating_app/login.html'), name='login'),
```

**project_urls/dating_app**

```
 path('', include('dating_app.urls', namespace= 'dating_app')),
```

**project_directory**

```
   .
├── 11_env
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   └── pyvenv.cfg
├── dating_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── chat.html
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── tag.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── templatetags
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── dating_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
└── manage.py
```

Comment: try to set `LOGIN_URL = '/login/'`

Comment: that worked. put it as an answer and I'll upvote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your URL configuration, you should set `LOGIN_URL` as

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
```